# How to convert win32 CHAR(char) type to std string?

Tags: c++, winapi, stdout, std

Im using the win32 function ReadFile:

```
CHAR lpBuffer[256];
DWORD nBytesRead;
DWORD nCharsWritten;

ReadFile(hPipeRead,lpBuffer,sizeof(lpBuffer),
                                      &nBytesRead,NULL) || !nBytesRead)
```

now im catcing the response from stdout in to lpBuffer with this i like to convert it to std string , the problem is when i do simple :

```
std::string szReturnlpBuffer(lpBuffer);
```

the value of the szReturnlpBuffer contains alot of garbege carecthers after the real string:
its looks like this the szReturnlpBuffer value :

> "Im stdout from the Qt
>   applicationÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ"

what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: If it's a Qt application, why not use QString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the string:

```
std::string szReturnlpBuffer(lpBuffer, nBytesRead);
```

because otherwise it reads till it finds a null character, which causes undefined behavior when it gets outside `lpBuffer`'s memory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to terminate the string with a null character:

```
lpBuffer[nBytesread] = '\0';
```